# How do you get the height of the block 1 after the blocks collides with block 2 on a frictionless ramp?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, energy-conservation, potential-energy

to get the initial height of block 1, i did mgh = 1/2(mv^2) so, 9.8(1.4)= 1/2(v^2)
and ended up getting v = 5.238. I'm not sure how to go on doing the rest.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the tutorials at http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/energy

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) . You might get a better response at a more appropriate site.  [Here’s one .](http://www.physicsforums.com), but there are others. They usually require a description of the specific difficulty.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

1. Find the speed of block 1 at the bottom of the ramp.
2. Use conservation of energy and momentum to find out the speed with which block 1 rebounds after the collision with block 2. An easy way of applying conservation of energy is the Law of Restitution : relative speed of separation = relative speed of approach.
3. Do the reverse of the calculation in 1 to get the height which block 1 reaches up the ramp.

---

Suppose the speed of block 1 when it reaches the bottom of the ramp is $u$.

It collides with block 2. Suppose block 2 moves forward with speed $v$ after the collision and block 1 rebounds with speed $w$. The collision is elastic so the relative velocity after the collision equals the relative velocity before collision : $w+v=u$.

Momentum is preserved in the collision so $1u=7v-1w=7(u-w)-1w=7u-8w$. Hence $8w=6u$ and $w=\frac34 u$.

Block 1 started from height $h_1$. It will return to height $h_2$ given by $$\frac{h_2}{h_1}=\frac{w^2}{u^2}=\frac{9}{16}$$